# Doubt in one step of the proof.

Tags: calculus, analysis, solution-verification, lagrange-multiplier, implicit-function-theorem

I'm dubious in step one proof. The reference I'm following claims to use the Implicit Function Theorem, but I haven't seen where it was used.

**Lagrange Multipliers Theorem:** Let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ a differential function in a open $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ and $M = \varphi^{-1}(c)$ a orietable surface in $U$, inverse image of regular value $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$ by a aplication $\varphi:U \to \mathbb{R}^n$, of class $C^1$. A point $p \in M$ is critic of restriction $f|M$ iff there exists $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ such that
$$\nabla f(p) = \lambda_1 \cdot \nabla \varphi_1 (p) + \ldots + \lambda_n \cdot \nabla \varphi_n(p),$$
where $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n: U \to \mathbb{R}$ are the coordinates of $\varphi$.

*Proof:* Assume the notation of the statement. Since $c$ is a regular value of $\varphi$, then for each $x \in M$, the vectors $\nabla \varphi_1 (x) ,\ldots, \nabla \varphi_n(x)$ are linearly independent and so this form a basis of vector space normal in $M$ in the point $x$, denoted by $(T_xM)^{\bot}$. In this case, if $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function, then $p \in M$ is a critic point of the $f|M$ iff the vector $\nabla f(p)$ is a linear combination of vectors $\varphi_i (p)$, ie,  there exists $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ such that
$$\nabla f(p) = \lambda_1 \cdot \nabla \varphi_1 (p) + \ldots + \lambda_n \cdot \nabla \varphi_n(p).$$

I can't figure out where he used the implicit function theorem, I believe it's to show that those vectors form the basis, but I'm not convinced of that. I looked at the case in one variable, it seems to be in that step. Thank you in advance for the tips.

Next I did a proof trying to explain where the theorem was used.

*Proof*: If $x \in M$, then by $M = \varphi^{-1}(c)$, it follows that $\varphi(x) = c$ and so, since $c$ is a regular value of $\varphi=(\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n):U \to \mathbb{R}^n$, then $\nabla \varphi_i(x) \neq 0$, for all $i = 1 ,\ldots, n$. Thus, by the implicit function theorem, there exists a open $Z \subset U$ with $x \in Z$ such that $\varphi^{-1}(c) \cap Z$ is the graphic of function $\xi:V \to \mathbb{R}^n$, o class $C^k$ in a open $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, considering the open $V$, we have that the set $\{\nabla \varphi_1 (x), \ldots, \nabla \varphi_n(x)\}$ is  linearly independent and so this form a basis of vector space normal in $M$ in the point $x$, denoted by $(T_xM)^{\bot}$. In this case, if $f:U \to \mathbb{R}$ a differentiable function, then $p \in M$ is a critic point of the $f|M$ iff the vector $\nabla f(p)$ is a linear combination of vectors $\varphi_i (p)$, ie,  there exists $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ such that
$$\nabla f(p) = \lambda_1 \cdot \nabla \varphi_1 (p) + \ldots + \lambda_n \cdot \nabla \varphi_n(p).$$

Is this second version correct? I'm not convinced it's right.

In short, my question is: at what point is the Implicit Function Theorem being used.

Taking the question, I would like to ask what would be another interesting application of this theorem in the context of analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What's the context of the author claiming to use the  implicit function theorem?

Comment: yes, basically. Else they are not linear independent because there is no inverse... or that there are multiple values so you have to restrict the function down to a set from which it is injective. Those gradients along p then form a vector space which isn't degenerate. Else f(p) could not be represented. The implicit function theorem allows us to essentially treat a part of a function as injective and therefore invert it. The IFT guarantee's, under the criteria, that we can invert the function. It lets us compute $f^{-1}$ in a "roundabout" way.

Comment: In the theorem it specifically talks about M which is the inverse image of a critical point. What is really going on is that the IFT is being used to provide a basis at the point c. $\varphi$ is essentially a linear functional that acts as an injective substitute for $f(p) = c$. We do $p = f^{-1}(c)$ but we don't know if $f$ is injective, but $\varphi$ is by the IFT and we have a linear representation for it and so we then can represent $\nabla f$ in as a linear combination.

Comment: The basic idea is that we can represent the function $f$ implicitly as a linear combination of values and this ultimately comes from the inverse function theorem. If you know the constant rank theorem then it is better to think of that as to see it more clearly and that is what I'm mainly trying to explain.

Comment: In this caso, the theorem is applied to the function $\varphi$, correct?

Comment: I put a proof at the end of the question, which is how I understood the application of the theorem to be. That's it?

Comment: Yes basically to get hold of a local parametrization by a C1-smooth function on the manifold(equivalent definition of a manifold in R^n in fact), we apply the implicit function theorem on the usual definition of a manifold in R^n. Another subtle place perhaps would be regarding the dimension of the tangent space.